# Keep inner rectangle the same aspect ratio when rotated inside outer rectangle

Tags: geometry

I am having some problems trying to calculate the correct width/height of a rectangle inside another when rotated.

Let's define our problem using algebraic expressions:

- The outer rectangle has dimensions $(W_o \times H_o).$
- The inner rectangle before rotation is positioned with its top-left corner at $(X, Y)$ and has dimensions $W_i \times H_i$. These dimensions and positions are expressed as percentages of the outer rectangle's dimensions:

  - $X = \alpha W_o$
  - $Y = \beta H_o$
  - $W_i = \gamma W_o$
  - $H_i = \delta H_o$

where $0 < \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta < 1$ are the percentage values.

Given a rotation of the inner rectangle by an angle $\theta$ about its center, I aim to find the new values $\alpha', \beta', \gamma', \delta'$ that describe the position and dimensions of the rotated inner rectangle such that it remains fully inside the outer rectangle without exceeding its bounds.

The challenge arises from ensuring the rotated rectangle's corners do not extend beyond the outer rectangle, thus necessitating an adjustment of the inner rectangle's dimensions and/or position while preserving the percentage-based relationship to the outer rectangle's dimensions.

I am looking for a method that can calculate the adjusted values of $\alpha', \beta', \gamma', \delta'$ after the inner rectangle is rotated by $\theta$ degrees.

The rotational center is the center point of the inner (red) rectangle

Thanks

[image]
After Rotation

[image: TwoRectangles]

Comment: Unclear (to me). If you add  pictures showing the results of some allowable rotations that may help us. How do you specify a rotation? By a center and an angle? Are you looking for the maximum possible rotation? What does "maintain its margins" mean? Please [edit] the question to tell us as much as possible along these lines.

Comment: Can you, please, describe what you want to achieve exactly? What does it mean: "I need to be able to apply rotation.."? How do you want us to rotate the inner rectangle? What does "maintaining the margins" mean? Please also try to use $\TeX$ to write mathematical formulas.

Comment: What is the centre of rotation?

Comment: I have added some more detail and an extra image, I hope it's enough. Thank you

Comment: Not nearly enough yet. The aspect ratio of the rotated rectangle has changed although the question title says it should be maintained.  What are its dimensions and how are they determined? Where is it located? What is the center of rotation?

Comment: @StevenYates If I have understood correctly you are looking for the **percentages** such that the inner rectangle still stays in the big rectangle when it is rotated. $\quad$ It is still unclear to me what are $x$ and $y$. Are they the coordinates of the center of the  inner rectangle? Or of one of the sides? What is the axys of rotation?

Comment: EthanBolker my images are not exact which isn't helping. I am not familiar with tools I can use to acuratley represent this problem visually :( I'm new to math.stackexchange

@Marco Yes, I am looking for the new size of the inner rectangle so that it stays within the bounds of the outer rectangle, if it gets rotated.

x & y are the top left corner of the inner rectangle starting position. The inner rectangles width and height are determined as a percentage of the outer rectangle. This works fine when no rotation is involved.

The center of rotation is the middle of the inner rectangle

Comment: I have updated it again. I hope this is better?

Answer (score 2):

With the notation introduced in the question statement, and using a Cartesian coordinate system with its origin at the top left corner of the outer rectangle, it follows that the center of the inner rectangle is at

$ X_c = X + \dfrac{1}{2} W_i $

$ Y_c = - ( Y + \dfrac{1}{2} H_i )$

And these coordinates are fixed.

Now, starting at the top left corner, and moving clockwise, the scaled inner rectangle has its vertices at

$ A =( X_c - s W_i /2, Y_c + s H_i/2 ) $

$ B =( X_c + s W_i/2 , Y_c + s H_i/2 ) $

$ C = (X_c + s W_i/2 , Y_c - s H_i/2 ) $

$ D = (X_c - s W_i/2, Y_c - s H_i/2 ) $

where $s$ is the scale factor.  Note that this way, the aspect ratio of the inner rectangle is preserved.

Let $W'_i = W_i/2 $ and $H'_i = H_i/2 $

Applying a rotation by an angle $\theta$ counter clockwise about the center of the inner rectangle gives the new coordinates of its four vertices as follows:

$A'_x = X_c + \cos \theta ( - s W'_i  ) - \sin \theta ( s H'_i ) = X_c + s ( - W'_i \cos \theta - H'_i \sin \theta) $

$A'_y = Y_C + \sin \theta (- s W'_i) + \cos \theta (s H'_i ) = Y_c + s ( H'_i \cos \theta - W'_i \sin \theta ) $

$B'_x = X_c + \cos \theta (  s W'_i ) - \sin \theta ( s H'_i ) = X_c + s ( W'_i \cos \theta - H'_i \sin \theta ) $

$B'_y = Y_c + \sin \theta ( s W'_i) + \cos \theta (s H'_i ) = Y_c + s (W'_i \sin \theta + H'_i \cos \theta ) $

$C'_x = X_c + \cos \theta (  s W'_i ) - \sin \theta (- s H'_i ) = X_c + s ( W'_i \cos \theta + H'_i \sin \theta ) $

$C'_y = Y_C + \sin \theta (s W'_i) + \cos \theta (-s H'_i ) = Y_c + s ( W'_i \sin \theta - H'_i \cos \theta ) $

$D'_x = X_c + \cos \theta ( - s W'_i ) - \sin \theta (- s H'_i ) = X_c + s( - W'_i \cos \theta + H'_i \sin \theta ) $

$D'_y = Y_c + \sin \theta (- s W'_i) + \cos \theta (-s H'_i ) = Y_c + s (- W'_i \sin \theta - H'_i \cos \theta )$

Now, let's define the following coefficients of $s$

$E_1 =  - W'_i \cos \theta - H'_i \sin \theta $

$ E_2 = H'_i \cos \theta - W'_i \sin \theta $

$ E_3 = W'_i \cos \theta - H'_i \sin \theta $

$E_4 = W'_i \sin \theta + H'_i \cos \theta  $

Then, we have

$A'_x = X_c + s E_1 $

$A'_y =  Y_c + s E_2 $

$B'_x = X_c + s E_3 $

$B'_y = Y_c + s E_4 $

$C'_x =  X_c - s E_1 $

$ C'_y = Y_c - s E_2 $

$D'_x = X_c - s E_3 $

$D'_y = Y_c - s E_4 $

Now the horizontal boundaries of the outer rectangle are given by the two lines

$ y = 0 $

$ y = - H_o $

So we have to ensure that

$ - H_o \le A'_y , B'_y, C'_y , D'_y \le 0 $

This means that we want

$ - H_o - Y_c \le s E_2, s E_4, - s E_2, - s E_4 \le - Y_c $

To solve this inequality, choose

$ E_{24} = \text{max} (| E_2 |, | E_4 | ) $

Then

$ s_1 = \dfrac{1}{E_{24}} \text{min}( |Y_c|, | H_o + Yc | )  $

Similarly, the vertical boundaries of the outer rectangle are given by the two lines

$ x = 0 $

$ y = W_o $

So we have to ensure that

$ 0 \le A'_x, B'_x, C'_x, D'_x \le W_o $

that is,

$ - X_c \le s E_1 , s E_3, -s E1, -s E_3 \le W_o - X_c $

And similar to the horziontal boundaries, the solution of this inequality is by defining

$E_{13} = \text{max}({ | E_{1}|, |E_{3}| })$

Then

$s_2 = \dfrac{1}{E_{13}} \text{min}( |X_c| , |W_o - X_c| ) $

Now our final scale factor is the minimum of $s_1$ and $s_2$

$s = \text{min}(s_1, s_2) $

If you want the scaled/rotated rectangle not to exceed the initial size, then you have to modify this to

$ s = \text{min}(1, s_1, s_2) $

I've implemented the above formulas, and your example, with $W_o = 300, H_o =100 $ for the outer rectangle, and $W_i = 180, H_i = 40 $ for the inner rectangle.  The top left corner of the unrotated/unscaled inner rectangle has coordinates $(30, -25)$.

Here's the figure illustrating rotation of the inner rectangle by $\theta = 60^\circ$ counter clockwise, about its fixed center which is at $(120, -45)$.

[image]

And here's another example with $W_o = 300, H_o = 200, W_i = 180, H_i= 80$, and the top left corner of the unrotate/unscaled inner rectangle is at $(30, -50)$.  The image is a .GIF image illustrating that the rotated/scaled rectangle stays within the bounds of the outer rectangle for all angles $\theta \in [0, 360^\circ]$.

[image]

Comment: @StevenYates  If my solution answered your question satisfactorily, then please upvote and accept it.  If you have questions on the solution, I'll be happy to answer them.